# Change default touch events for UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, overriding, touch

Alright, so here is what I am trying to do.  I have a UITextField.  When I single tap it, I want to call one of my methods.  When I double tap (tap it twice with 1 finger) it, I want to edit the text field (as though I had single tapped it on a normal UITextField.)

I am not sure how to go about this.  I was thinking of sub-classing UITextField and trying to intercept the touch event as it is sent, but I can't figure out which methods to override to do this.  Which methods should I override and how?

Or, if there is a better way to do this, let me know!  I'm all ears, and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would involve several steps:

1.) Add a NSBoolean property that keeps track of whether the user has already tapped the field once recently (you get to decide what recently means here).

2.) Implement the textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method of the delegate assigned to your UITextField.  If the user has tapped twice in quick succession (detectable by checking whether or not the boolean property is true), then return YES.  If not, call your method, and then return NO.

Comment: A word of caution here. That method triggers in more cases than just tapping, for example when pressing tab on an external keyboard to traverse text fields. Tested on iOS 9.