# How can I respond to touch events on a UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to respond to touch events (specifically `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`) on a  `UITextField`, but the only event that comes through is `UIControlEventTouchCancel`.

I can't use `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`, because it only occurs when field gains focus, which is not what I'm trying to detect.  I want to know when the user lifts their finger, and whether it was inside or outside the text field, regardless of current focus state.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

To be clear I've tried using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` and it *does not work*.  The touch up event is prevented by the cancel.  I want a way to detect the touch up *before* the `UITextField` consumes it and produces the Cancel event.

Also, I'd like to avoid creating any extra views if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Well a round about way of doing it would be to create a UIButton with the fill set to clear to cover all of the space, and a UITextField on top of it. If the user touches in the text field, the text field should send an event, and if the user touches outside of the text field, the UIButton will send the event.

Comment: Since I can't get the event from touching inside the TextField, this won't work.  I'd also like to avoid creating any extra views if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Good answer here:
[Change default touch events for UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702617/change-default-touch-events-for-uitextfield?rq=1)

Use the text field's delegate and do what you want to do in textFieldShouldBeginEditing:

You can return NO to prevent the default behavior.

Comment: That's not useless information, it could help me come closer to the behavior I want.  It's not a complete answer though, as it can't help me detect touches that begin inside and end outside the field the way `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` would.

Comment: A word of caution here. That method triggers in more cases than just tapping, for example when pressing tab on an external keyboard to traverse text fields. Tested on iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can create category for the UiView and override the touchesBegan meathod as follows.

It is working fine for me.And it is centralize solution for this problem.

```
#import "UIView+Keyboard.h"
@implementation UIView(Keyboard)

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.window endEditing:true];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem just today. My goal was to change textfield's background color on touch down and revert it back on touch up/cancel.
It is weird that touch down is sent to target from UITextField, but touch up inside, touch up outside and even touch cancel are not.
I found the solution. It is simple. Just create a subclass of UITextField and override touchesEnded: and touchesCancelled:.

```
@interface TextField : UITextField

@end

@implementation CuteTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.backgroundColor=GetDefaultBackgroundColor();
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    self.backgroundColor=GetDefaultBackgroundColor();
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a target for your desired event programatically, or, use IB.

```
UITextField * touchyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 21.0)];

[touchyTextField addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(yourDesiredMethod) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: No, that definitely doesn't work.  First thing I tried.  The "yourDesiredMethod" method is never called.
I can get events for UIControlEventTouchDown, but the neither of the TouchUp events is fired.  Instead, a UIControlEventTouchCancel event is fired.  I can't just use that event as a hacky proxy for the event I want either, because it is also fired when the long press brings up the magnification loop and when something else cancels the  user input such as a modal dialog or the lock screen.

Comment: Wow, I assumed that it would work like any other UIView based class.  You may be able to create a custom UITextField and override the touchesBegan: method, ensuring to become the first responder in proper cases so the keyboard still shows.

Comment: So, I tried overriding touchesBegan/Ended/Cancelled, and that also gave me a Began/Cancelled pair, with no Ended event.  This is really frustrating!  Also, overriding those methods didn't prevent the textField from becoming first responder, so the base class is doing touch handling before I get the chance!

Comment: You can handle touch up inside in textFieldShouldBeginEditing in UITextFieldDelegate.