# iOS - can't scroll table if I start scroll by touch on a textField inside of a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a form - table view with labels and text fields. Labels on left side of each cell, text fields on the right. I can't scroll table if I start scrolling by touch on a text field. I understand why this happens but is there any workaround?

Comment: don't use a text field/disable scrolling. Then just resize the cell as the text gets bigger instead of allowing scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can [change the touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702617/change-default-touch-events-for-uitextfield), and then make a function which detect when you scroll : If you scroll unset the touch event (maybe with unsetting the delegate), otherwise just let you UITexfield began editing.
I'm sorry I can't provide you some code or testing it, I don't have XCode no more...